# Elegant solution for string parsing

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, loops

so i got a dozen of strings which i download, example's below which i need to parse.

"Australija      036 AUD    1        4,713831        4,728015        4,742199"

"Vel. Britanija  826 GBP    1       10,300331       10,331325       10,362319"

So my first idea was to count manually where the number i need is (the second one, 4,728015 or 10,331325 in exampels up) and get substring.(52,8) 
But then i realized that few of the the strings im parsing has a >9 number in it, so i would need a substring of (51,9) for that case, so i cant do it this way

Second idea was to save all the number like chars in a vector, and then get vector[4] and save it into a seperate variable.

And third one is to just loop the string until i position myself after the 5th group of spaces and then substring it.

Just looking for some feedback on what would be "best".

Comment: make space-delimited substrings using getline. merge early ones until you have 7. use group 5

Comment: The data format makes an *elegant* solution difficult, especially since spaces are allowed in the first field.  I suggest reading as a line of text and searching for the first non-digit character; which defines the content of the first field.  The rest of the fields can be extracted using `std::istringstream` and `operator>>`.

Comment: Kind of newbie here,could i trouble you for a code example?

Comment: You want somebody to do your homework?

Comment: It's called "Asking for help". Im sure you once used that technique while you were a newb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem**

is that we can have multiple words at the beginning of the string. I.e. the first element may contain spaces.

**The solution**

Start from the end of the string where we are stable.

Split the string up at the spaces. Start counting from the end, and pick the previous-last element.

Solution 1: Boost string algorithms

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

string extractstring(string & fullstring)
{
    vector<string> vs;
    split(vs, fullstring);
    return vs[vs.size() - 2];
}
```

Solution 2: QString (from Qt framework)

```
#include <QString>
QString extractstring(QString & fullstring)
{
    QStringlist sl = fullstring.split(" ");
    return sl[vs.size() - 2];
}
```

Solution 3: STL only

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

string extractstring(string & fullstring) 
{
    istringstream iss(fullstring);
    vector<string> elements;
    copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss),
         istream_iterator<string>(),
         back_inserter(elements));
    return elements[elements.size() - 2];
}
```

Other solutions: regex, C-pointer acrobatic.

**Update:**

I would not use `sscanf` based solutions because it may be difficult to identify multiple words at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do it with a single line using `sscanf`?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/

For example (http://ideone.com/e2cCT9):

```
char *str = "Australija 4,713831 4,728015 4,742199";
char tmp[255];
int a,b,c,d;
sscanf(str, "%*[^0-9] %d,%d %d,%d", &a, &b, &c, &d);

printf("Parsed values: %d %d %d %d\n",a,b,c,d);
```

Comment: Well, im not sure i can't tell the function to specificly pick the second decimal number from the string.

Comment: @puernos please be more specific on how you'd like to parse the string and read the doc

Comment: any way it works,
i just need to get the second number in a seperate variable, so i can save it in a map.

Comment: @sp2danny updated format string. Now it will just skip all chars and get only numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The hurdle is that the first field is allowed to have spaces, but the remaining fields are separated by spaces.

This may not be elegant, but the concept should work:

```
std::string text_line;
getline(my_file, text_line);
std::string::size_type field_1_start;
const unsigned int text_length = text_line.length();
for (field_1_start = 0; field_1_start < text_length; ++field_1_start)
{
  if (is_digit(text_line[field_1_start])
  {
    break;
  }
}
if (field_1_start < text_length)
{
  std::string remaining_text = text_line.substr(field_1_start, text_length - field_1_start);
  std::istringstream input_data(remaining_text);
  int field_1;
  std::string field2;
  input_data >> field_1;
  input_data >> field_2;
  //...
}
```